# Two graphic cards: Which one will be selected to display the BIOS/POST information?

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard, bios

On a system with two graphic cards, which one will be selected to display the BIOS/POST information?  How is the selection performed?  By PCIe slot #?

I find lots of information on how to setup the framebuffer or X, but nothing prior booting from the hard disk.

In my case, I have an old, but very good, Intel DX58SO Motherboard.  I am planing to have two graphic cards, one for host display, the other remaining inactive until a VM claims it.  I want to be sure that the BIOS booting select the graphic card I plan to use for the host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, "the BIOS will use whatever the BIOS decides to use".

In some cases, a BIOS will offer a configuration option.  e.g., by specifying a slot, or at least a slot type like PCI or PCIe (or AGP for older systems).

Slot number is often related to what the BIOS chooses for this, so swapping the slot number may impact boot order (and have no real impact on anything else).